# connecting converse.js with fastpath in openfire

Tags: javascript, openfire, strophe, converse.js

I have installed openfire with the fastpath plugin.
Using the inverse plugin i can redirect the user to the appropriate queue in a workgroup.

Now, i am trying to add converse.js to a page having the same functionality. I can see and chat with the other contacts, but when fastpath tries to put me into a conference with the respective agent (based on a question) i get an error.

Here is my js:

```
  converse.initialize({
            bosh_service_url: 'http://chat.domain.com:7070/http-bind/',
            show_controlbox_by_default: true,
            allow_muc_invitations: true,
            keepalive: true,
            debug: true,
            allow_non_roster_messaging: true,
            allow_contact_requests: true,
            auto_join_on_invite: true,
            roster_groups: true,
            jid: 'user@chat.domain.com',
            password: 'password',
            auto_login: true,
            auto_subscribe: true
           });
```

On:

```
_converse.onDirectMUCInvitation = function (message) {
 var x_el = message.querySelector('x[xmlns="jabber:x:conference"]'),
        from = Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(message.getAttribute('from')),
        room_jid = x_el.getAttribute('jid'),
        reason = x_el.getAttribute('reason');}
```

x_el is null despite the fact that the message contains the following:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" 
from="pjiw6d129@conference.chat.domain.com" 
to="user@chat.domain.com/converse.js-60521038">
<workgroup xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/workgroup" jid="test@workgroup.chat.domain.com"/>
<session xmlns="http://jivesoftware.com/protocol/workgroup" id="pjiw6d129"/>
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
    <invite from="test@workgroup.chat.domain.com">
        <reason>Please join me for a chat.</reason>
    </invite>
</x>
<x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" jid="pjiw6d129@conference.chat.domain.com"/>
```

I am missing something but can't quite see it.

Thank you for the help!

---

The problem was at the querySelector, replaced

```
room_jid = x_el.getAttribute('jid'),
reason = x_el.getAttribute('reason');}
```

with

```
room_jid = message.getElementsByTagName('x')[1].getAttribute('jid'),
reason = message.getElementsByTagName('x')[0].getAttribute('reason');
```

in converse.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openfire's FastPath is an implementation of the XMPP extension [XEP-0142: Workgroup Queues](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html). To the best of my knowledge, converse.js (version 3.3.2, which is the most recent release at the time that I write this), does not support this extension.

Comment: i just wanted to use converse as an XMPP client. There is no need for it to support XEP-0142.